# Retrieve an item from FirebaseListObservable using observable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/find';



@Injectable()
export class TeamService {
teams: FirebaseListObservable<any> = this.af.database.list('/teams', {       preserveSnapshot: true });
constructor(public af: AngularFire) {

}

TeamByKey(key) {
    return this.teams.find((teams: any) => {
        for (let team of teams) {
            if (team.key == key)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    })
}
}
```

I want to retrieve the team when I have found the good key. But the function return the whole list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value emitted by the AngularFire2 `list` observable is an array. The `find` operator finds emitted values that match the predicate, so when you find the `team` and return `true`, the `find` operator condsiders the `teams` value to have been found and that's why the whole list of teams is emitted.

To emit only the matching team, use the `map` operator and the `Array.prototype.find` method:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
...
TeamByKey(key) {
    return this.teams.map((teams: any[]) => teams.find((team: any) => team.key === key));
}
```